# How to manage Inquiries of more than one products?

Tags: web-development, design, management

I can't guess the perfect title of this question, so please read my case and please help me.

We have 4 different products. Each is having their own site and database, means they are totally independent.
Now I want a common system that can manage "contact us" page inquiries.
Moreover I can pull out the contact inquires from each database. And even I should be able to send bulk mail to all of them. etc etc.

So what kind of application is this? Is there any software available? If yes then which are those? Or do I need to create a new custom application?

Please advise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were working with this situation I would just write an app do what needs to be done.  It's highly unlikely that you find something out there to match your needs (or even get close).

Writing it yourself ensures that the correct data is being pulled from the correct field/database and delivered how/when you want it delivered.

Comment: +1 - "It's highly unlikely that you find something out there to match your needs".  Very, very true.  Build it yourself!

Comment: How about use CRM??